# Trying to set prices to extended decimal/BTC in Rails on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, heroku

So I'm relatively new to Rails, but have been trying to build a little store to sell some things for bitcoin.  When I run my storefront on my local environment my pricing looks great (i.e. a book for .001 BTC), yet when I push it live to Heroku, my price rounds itself to the nearest 100th.(i.e. .016 becomes .02 or .001 becomes .00).  Any ideas?  Here is my product.rb file that validates my ":price".

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :price, :title, :image_url, :description, :orders
  has_many :line_items
  has_many :orders, through: :line_items
  before_destroy :ensure_not_referenced_by_any_line_item    

  validates :title, :description, :image_url, presence: true
  validates :price, numericality: {greater_than_or_equal_to: 0.00000001}
  validates :title, uniqueness: true
  validates :image_url, allow_blank: true, format: {
    with:    %r{\.(gif|jpg|png)$}i,
    message: 'must be a URL for GIF, JPG, or PNG image.'
  }
```

Here is my _line_item.html.erb file:

```
<% if line_item == @current_item %>
<tr id="current_item">
<% else %>
<tr>
<% end %>
  <td><%= line_item.quantity %>&times;</td>
  <td><%= line_item.product.title %></td>
  <td class="item_price"><%= line_item.total_price %>&nbspBTC</td>
</tr>
```

My code is based on the Agile Web Development with Rails book's Depot app... Thanks for any help!

Comment: It could be 2 issues -- your DB is not handling decimals, or your front-end could be causing problems. To ensure it's not the former problem, can you give us any more information about your production db setup?

Comment: Sure, on my local machine I am using SQLite3 while production db is PostGreSQL.  Anything more I can tell you that might help?

Comment: Can you post your database migration? keep in mind with postgres you're concerned with [these](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/datatype-numeric.html) underlying number types.

Comment: After further inspection of my DB migration, I realize that I had set the precision to 8 and the scale to 2.  Thanks for the help Rich and Mike!

Comment: And thank you Carol for fixing my code up in the initial question!

Answer (score 1):

After further inspection of my DB migration (depot/db/timestamp_create_products.rb), I realize that I had set the precision to 8 and the scale to 2:

```
class CreateProducts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :products do |t|
      t.string :title
      t.text :description
      t.string :image_url
      t.decimal :price, precision: 8, scale: 2

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

So I just had to change that to this:

```
class CreateProducts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :products do |t|
      t.string :title
      t.text :description
      t.string :image_url
      t.decimal :price, precision: 9, scale: 8

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Thanks for telling me where I needed to look Rich and Mike!